# Excel Index Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The problem at hand is:
I have a list of projects (column A), each one with his current value (B).
I have another list (C) in which I want to specify a subset of projects that I want  to be considered.

[image]

So in column (D) I'd like to have the values:

```
640 
1240 
5296
```

I have tried with the formula in the picture, but something is wrong.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@spiderman77 Try:

=INDEX($A$1:$B$7,MATCH(C1,$A$1:$A$7,0),2)

Comment: To explain what's going on, for OP's understanding: You have your `MATCH` backwards:  The First Argument is "what value am I looking for" (i.e. the value in Column C on that Row), and the Second Argument is the List that you are looking for it *in* (i.e. the list in Column A)